# How to compare slopes between variables with different scales?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I want to compare the slopes of progression of a variable that is measured in percentage versus a variable that is measured in decibels. What is a good method to compare?

Comment: A decibel is on a log scale, which immediately suggests looking at the log of the other variable.  Any other consideration, to be applicable and relevant, would have to consider the nature of your data and the objective of your comparison.

Comment: The variable is measured in terms of a percentage of what?